# Django: DateField in Form must have different format

Tags: django

I have a DateField() object named `event_date`, and a view that renders an `<input type="text" />` widget.

My problem is that the DateField() object stores the date in the form `yyyy-mm-dd`, but the `<input>` field must accept the input in the form `dd.mm.yyyy`. This does not validate. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Did you override the datefield in the ModelForm

Comment: I use "from django.forms import ModelForm" to "import" the model, but I haven't override it

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to localize your inputs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#locale-aware-input-in-forms

Other way would be to use a custom field in the form.